# Auto add <!--netxpage--> tag in Wordpress post after 300 words

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

How can I automatically add nextpage tag in Wordpress posts? I have blog with long texts and want to show them like a book, divided in pages. 
I use this in my single.php but there is no second page of post:

```
<div class="post-content">
        <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 250 ,'<!--nextpage-->'); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
    </div>
```

In my theme pagination was single and I change it

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

'' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'author' ), 'after' => '', ) ); ?>

It's not an option manually to add nextpage tag or more, because some of texts are with 1000 pages

Answer (score 0):

[wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) This function trims text to a certain number of words and returns the trimmed text.

EX:-

```
wp_trim_words(get_the_content,500,'<!--nextpage-->');
```

it will put the `<!--nextpage-->` tag after 500 words..

Comment: you want to put <!--nextpage--> tag after certain words.. this is for that thing. if you want to create the whole new page then show some code of what have you done? at which stage you are facing problems..  no one will write the complete code for you. show some of your efforts..

Comment: I know that no one will write my code but I'm stuck with that for 3 days. Yes, I want to put <!--nextpage--> tag after certain words and split my post into couple of pages - 2, 3 or more, depends of how long is post. I will find a way. Thank you again!

Comment: if you have done something then update your question so that  we can have better idea.